# compilation based on environment variables

Tags: c, compilation, environment-variables

how can a section of code be compiled with dependency of an environment variable value?
i tried looking for how to use environment variables in c, but found only use as an argument to main, while i want it to affect the compilation process. i want to leave dome functions out of compilation.
also, how it can be done for leaving a complete files out of compilation?

saying the .h file will look like:

```
function_dec_1()
#ifdef ENV_VAR
relevant_macros
function_dec_2()
#endif
#funct_dec_3()
```

Comment: Maybe you could modify your makefile to build your program differently based on environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass anything you want, such as $(ENV_VAR) to the compiler via the -D flag, (for gcc anyway, otherwise check if your C compiler accepts -D)

so

```
EXPORT ENV_VAR=HELLO
cc -D$(ENV_VAR) hello.c
```

should act as if

```
#define HELLO
```

was at the start of your source file `hello.c`

Comment: how can I use the variable this way when the environment variable is not defined? i get the following error:
#if UNDEFINED_VAR
...
#endif

    error: #if with no expression

using ifndef does not help, probably it is defined with an empty value

Comment: That's what the EXPORT command does ... define the environment variable. If you're running some shell or OS where that command isn't available, such as Windows, you'll have to replace the EXPORT with the equivalent command for that OS.